# How to parse the many values of one-to-many relationship into HTML template in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, syntax-error, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many relationship in Django as such:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Images(models.Model):
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_urls = models.URLField(max_length = 200)
```

I have the following view defined:

```
from .models import Listing, Images

def index(request):
    All_Listings = Listing.objects.filter(isActive=True)
    return render(request, "index.html", {
        "All_Listings": All_Listings,
        "Images" : Images
    })
```

Now for each listing I want to show all related images in my HTML. I have tried to do the following:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
{% for listing in All_Listings %}
<h2>{{ list(Images.objects.filter(listings_id=2))  }}<h2>
{% endfor%}
{% endblock %}
(If this works, than later on I will replace 2 with listing.id)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Could not parse the remainder: '(Images.objects.filter(listings_id=2))' from 'list(Images.objects.filter(listings_id=2))'
```

However, when I run this from the terminal it works:

```
>>> list(Images.objects.filter(listings_id=2))
[<Images: https://www.kettererkunst.com/still/kunst/pic570/531/422000352-4.jpg>, <Images: https://www.kettererkunst.com/still/kunst/pic570/531/422000352-1.jpg>]
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: You should call database queries outside template engine and pass result to render context

Comment: I have thought about that, but how to approach this if I have 10 listings and each listing has 50 image urls? Should I parse every listing seperately?

Comment: No, your goal is achievable with listing.images_set.all inside template (although it's still bad doing it that way). The best way is to create a list of dict like `[{'listing': Listing, 'images': listing.images_set.all()} for listing in Listing.objects.filter(isActive=True)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the @property image in the Listing class, and query all the related Images in it.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  
    @property
    def images(self):
        return Images.objects.filter(listings=self)

class Images(models.Model):
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_urls = models.URLField(max_length = 200)
```

And then call `listing.images`  in the template:

```
{% for listing in All_Listings %}
   {%for image in listening.images%}
      {{ image }}
   {% endfor%}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Thank you, apologies for my noob approach, still learning. Elegant solution though.
Please change ```listening.images``` to ```listing.images```.